# Android KitKat Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

Is it possible to create an android application with storage access framework, which needs to work in older versions of android.

Regards,
RR

Comment: Did you try ? Or you want the world to try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as per Documentation **[Supporting devices running Android 4.3 and lower](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html)**:

> The ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT intent is only available on devices running
>   Android 4.4 and higher. If you want your application to support
>   ACTION_GET_CONTENT to accommodate devices that are running Android 4.3
>   and lower, you should disable the ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent filter in
>   your manifest for devices running Android 4.4 or higher.